# Prevent user from changing directory using rbash

Tags: bash, freebsd

I have created two new users in my FreeBSD unix environment and I want to limit their access to their respective home directories only.

After reading on the internet, I found a solution to modify `/etc/passwd` file and change their `bash` to `rbash` which will prevent them to run `CD` command.

so I run the following command to find where my `rbash` is ?

`where rbash`

and it gives the following output,

`usr/local/bin/rbash`

so I opened my `/etc/passwd` file and change the `/bin/sh` to `/usr/local/bin/rbash`.

After that I logged out and logged back in using the account for which I modified the settings but I could still run the `CD` command, or any other command for that matter.

Can anyone please tell me why it is not working ?
Can this be done using `Samba` or any other solution ?

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208960/how-to-restrict-a-user-to-one-folder-and-not-allow-them-to-move-out-his-folder) might be of interest to you. :D

Comment: You realize that `cd` is completely irrelevant for restricting access, since it only defines which base directory your relative paths are relative to.

Comment: Editing `/etc/passwd` won't change the user's shell. Use `chsh` or `chpass -s`, or, if you need to, `vipw`, which lets you edit `master.passwd` and rebuilds the user database.